# Oracle JDBC OCI client - how it selects character set

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle-call-interface, ojdbc

I am using Oracle JDBC OCI driver on my Windows PC.
When my application (Java project with ojdbc6.jar library)connects to DB, in the handshake stage it specifies main and secondary character sets as 0x98 =  RU8PC866

I need my client to specify 0x367 = AL32UTF8 character set as main and secondary character set.
I've changed NLSLANG parameter at registry to AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8, no success, so help needed

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your Java application:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.<your locale here>);
```

It's derived from java.util.Locale iirc.

If that's still not working, you might need the `orai18n.jar` that (iirc) contains more character sets than the ojdbc6.jar (use it in addition to the ojdbc6.jar not as a replacement).

You might also be able to set the locale by using `-Duser` parameters when invoking your application.